# How do I change backgroundcolor attribute of a div in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to change the background color of a div, depending if the person using my website answered the question right(green), or wrong(red). I am using conditional statements and prompt for the questions. 
So basically I have a code that looks similar to this

```
      if(q1 === "ubuntu") {
         div1.innerHTML="Right answer!"
         counter ++;
         //here would be the place where I want to put the code that makes another div change it's color
      } else {
         div.innerHTML="Wrong answer!"
      }
```

Comment: Have you considered div.style.backgroundColor?

Comment: I didn't, but now I see it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All HTML elements have a style property so you can change the color(text color) or the background color of a div by setting `div1.style.color = "#54b37a"` or `div1.style.backgroundColor = "#54b37a"` respectively depending on you needs

Comment: That was it! Thanks!